# javascript closure on function objects

Tags: javascript, closures

Why does closure behavior not come into play here:

```js
function init(){
  for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
  
  function timer() {
    var k=i;
    console.log("in timer");
    console.log(timer.i);
    console.log(k);
  }
  
  timer.i = i;
  setTimeout(timer, 0);
  
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="init()";>
</body>
```

Why does timer.i not take the last value of i on the outer function init's stack? However, it does take the outer for k.

Comment: Please format your code before asking other people to look at it.

Comment: What is your question? Your code does what I would expect.

Comment: For your next tests: you don't have to wait 10000 millisecondes. In fact even a timeout of 0 is enough.

Comment: the question is for the value taken by timer.i , made the edits to 0

Answer (score 0):

Function declaration in EcmaScript 6 are now block-scoped, just like `let` declarations (with the difference with `let` that the variable is declared in the outer global/functionnal scope).

Your code is globally equivalent to

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
  let timer = function() {
    console.log("in timer");
    console.log(timer.i);
  }
  timer.i = i;
  setTimeout(timer, 1000);
}
```

This means you have different `timer` values.

Note that if you had used `var` instead of `let` and instead of a function declaration, you *would* have got twice the same log.

A good read: http://2ality.com/2015/02/es6-scoping.html

Please note that adding properties to a function isn't really a good practice. You should use scope variables for this, for example:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
  let timer_i = i;
  setTimeout(function timer(){
    console.log("in timer");
    console.log(timer_i);
  }, 1000);
}
```

which in this simple case could be just written as

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
  setTimeout(function timer(){
    console.log("in timer");
    console.log(i);
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I think it would be clearer to have the number as this.timer

Comment: If I do a `var k =i`  inside the function  and `console.log(k)` inside the function then it retains a reference to outer i.

Comment: `Function declaration in EcmaScript 6 are now block-scoped` No, they're still assigned to the *outer* (function) scope, even though the assignment only occurs when the interpreter comes to the `function` line

Comment: @CertainPerformance please read the chapter 7 of the page I link to. It will be clearer. It is hoisted *and* block-scoped.

Comment: @mplungjan this.i may be problem if timer was an event handler.

Comment: wait wait wait, functions are block scoped now? What gives! Why?

Comment: Function *declerations* are block scoped. Same as multiple instances of the same anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually *two* `timer`s. When the interpreter runs across a function declaration inside a loop like that, it will *overwrite* the previous function name in the outer scope (if such a function exists). This snippet might make it clearer:

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
  const oldTimer = window.timer;
  function timer() {
    console.log("in timer");
    console.log(timer.i);
  }
  timer.i = i;
  console.log('oldTimer is ' + oldTimer + (oldTimer ? ' with i of ' + oldTimer.i : ''));
  console.log('is oldTimer the same as the new timer? ' + (oldTimer === timer));
  setTimeout(timer, 1000);
}
console.log('Outside of for loop: timer is ' + typeof timer);
```

(The `timer` is still available outside of the `for` loop - it gets added to the global object.)

Comment: should both the timer.i   's  not inherit the value of i from the outer? Even after the second timer block is defined/run over?

Comment: No, because `timer.i` is assigned to the separate timers, synchronously, inside the loop. The `timer.i` is not a reference to the final value of the `i`, but a copy of the `i` at the moment it was assigned to the `i` property of the function.

Comment: True, it still confused me why it shouldn't think the same for var k=i, each var k=i also belongs to a different timer. Or basically it doesn't invoke the function so it does not do the assigment? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know what `k` you're referring to, but `var`s are hoisted and have unintuitive function scope rather than block scope (generally, always use `const` or `let` instead)